# Update Query with INNER JOIN between tables?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to Update a column in a table in one database after doing  inner join. While using the given below query is showing an error. The error is : `"Unable to parse query text."` Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

SQL:

```
UPDATE  tbl_plan SET Mail_Status = 'Sent' INNER JOIN
tbl_Assignment ON tbl_Assignment.Plan_ID = tbl_plan.Plan_ID
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, { fn NOW() }, Date) = 2) AND (Mail_Status IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got the format of an update query with a join in it slightly wrong. Try this instead

```
UPDATE p  
SET Mail_Status = 'Sent' 
FROM tbl_plan p
INNER JOIN tbl_Assignment a ON a.Plan_ID = p.Plan_ID
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, { fn NOW() }, Date) = 2) AND (Mail_Status IS NULL)
```

Comment: While using the above query showing an error. The error is : "invalid object name p"

Comment: If you have copied it exactly it should work, the syntax is correct. Have you definitely aliased `tbl_plan` as `p `as in the from clause.

Comment: I have copied the same what you have posted above. I don't know why it is showing error.